# In Search Results order/sort by ordered quantity

Tags: magento

Please help me

I want to see the products in Search Results order by ordered quantity means which products are more sold those products shows at first

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Please read this block i think this is very helpful to you.

```
http://www.magento.cc/how-to-sortshow-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento.html 

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-products/sort-show-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento/
```

For last one i am not sure because this block taking about filter not a sorting.

Comment: Thanq very much to replay...

Actually i was enabled this order in product listing page. But now i am trying to enable order after search
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php

In this function : public function prepareProductCollection($collection)... have the query to get product collection...

pls help me..

Comment: Thanq very much to replay...
Actually i was enabled this order in product listing page. But now i am trying to enable order after search
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php
In this function : public function prepareProductCollection($collection)... have the query to get product collection...

Comment: orginal code:
$collection ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

Comment: custom code :
Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addOrderedQty()
->setOrder('ordered_qty','desc');
In this query i am unable to pass the searching word..
how can i pass that varible?

Please help me....

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText()) ->addOrderedQty() ->setOrder('ordered_qty','desc');

Comment: thanq..your replay
i tried that way..but i got this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addSearchFilter() in /var/www/bluestar-magento/11310dev/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php on line 59